# Playlists in 'Noise' disappear after restart

Tags: release-freya, music

When I create a playlist, it appears in the left column as it is supposed to. But just after one restart the space is clear and only the smart lists are shown. In the context menu of a song the playlist is shown (the song can be added to it) so it seems not to be deleted. I just can't see it.

Is there a fix around and does this occur to others?

PS: This issue appeared on two different computers with freya installed on them (and even before on luna).

Comment: Looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1434937).